# Angular 6 copy element and it's custom directives

Tags: angular, directive

I'm using angular 6 to complete a custom web building system. Now, what I need to do is: When I click on the element, and then click the copy and paste button, I can create the same sibling element. The new element can also have custom directive in the original element, then I can continue to operate the new element.

```
copyPaste(){
    this.selectedDom = this.service.getEvent();
    const dom = this.selectedDom.rd.createElement(this.selectedDom.el.nativeElement.localName);
    dom.innerHTML = this.selectedDom.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    const attr = this.selectedDom.el.nativeElement.attributes;
    const l = attr.length;
    for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
        dom.setAttribute(attr[i].nodeName,attr[i].value);
    }
    this.selectedDom.rd.appendChild(this.selectedDom.rd.parentNode(this.selectedDom.el.nativeElement),dom);
}
```

I add the directive to the new element by set attributes, but the directive doesn't work. I can't select and manipulate new elements.

What should I do to achieve this function? Can someone help me? Thank You!

Comment: if it's simply a form - use [angular reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). if it's more complicated than that I suggest [dynamic component loading](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Can you have more than one of the same element ? If so, then you should go for a dynamic component loading.

Comment: But there are a lot of different elements here, maybe a li, maybe a div with many elements